# IOS Facebook Auth - Keep Friends List Updated

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Login in an IOS app with the class

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:
```

That returns an Access Token. That Token is sent to the back-end, and user information is fetched with a Graph Call.

I would like to keep the facebook friends list udpated, so that each time the user logs in, his facebook friends list is updated.

I am confused with the different strategies to do so:

1. User opens app
2. Check Facebook token with [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]
3. If there is a currentAccessToken, send it to the server, fetch the friends list with a Graph Call (Server <-> Facebook)

Should that list be stored in the back-end or simply returned to the client and stored in the UserDefaults?

Is that the preferred way to do so with the server, or could some calls be made directly from the client to facebook (in case the list is not stored server-side)?

Thanks for your insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the preferred way, but you can make a Graph Call for the friends list on the client with this:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                              parameters:@{@"fields" : @"friends"}];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

or if you want the user's friendlists use:

```
@{@"fields" : @"friendlists"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right it's possible to use FBSDKGraphRequest to fetch that particular data.

The thing that is not really clear to me is which way to fetch data, once you have a token:

1. Should it be SERVER <-> FACEBOOK
2. Or FACEBOOK <-> CLIENT and then save the data CLIENT <-> SERVER

Comment: Well, you always want to look at where you're storing your data and try to make a simple architecture so all your clients can stay in sync with that data...so do <client Token> to SERVER <-> FACEBOOK, then do your friends list update check there, then if there's new data, update your stored data, then push it to the client. This architecture will allow the client to stay up-to-date with the server, which is up-to-date with facebook..soo <client Token> -> <server> -> <facebook> -> <server> -><client>

Comment: A different way of thinking about it is keeping your client "dumb and stupid". Does your client need to know if the friends list changed? Probably not. The client only needs the complete and latest list. Your database it the one who needs to know the changes. So give your database(server) that behavior, then just make your clients an observer of your database.